# global vs $GLOBALS in php

Tags: php, global

I know it's better to use passing by reference instead of doing this, but i'm wondering why would this code (Code 1) work fine but the other (Code 2) wouldn't ?

Code 1:

```
<?php

$var = 5;

function unset_var() {
     unset($GLOBALS['var']);
}

unset_var();
echo $var; //Notice: Undefined variable: var 
?>
```

Code 2:

```
<?php

$var = 5;

function unset_var() {
     global $var;
     unset($var); // trying to unset $var
}

unset_var();
echo $var; // 5
?>
```

Comment: The second example just severes the local name and reference from the global it referred to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second code has a function that creates a new variable and you're unsetting that one, not the one outside the function. Your first code manipulates only the $GLOBALS array.

Also you should avoid even thinking about global variables in the first place....

Comment: I thought about Globals `:-(`  I've just lost the Game.